# How to source a shell script and execute its functions in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby . I'm trying to source my shell script in ruby and execute functions in sourced shell script.

**below is my shell script** `/tmp/test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash


function hello {

        echo "hello, this script is being called from ruby"
}
```

**below is my ruby script** `test.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

system("source /tmp/test.sh")
puts $?.exitstatus

system("hello")
puts $?.exitstatus
```

**output using** `system`

```
[root@localhost ~]# ruby test.rb
127
127
```

I even tried the back tick approach, but i got below error

**code :**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

status=`source /root/test.sh`
puts status

status2=`hello`
puts status2
```

**error:**

```
ruby  test.rb
test.rb:3:in ``': No such file or directory - source (Errno::ENOENT)
        from test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

can anyone tell what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [session](https://github.com/ahoward/session) gem, or write a solution yourself.

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function hello() {
    echo "Hello, World!"
}
```

Ruby file:

```
IO.popen('bash', 'r+') do |sh|
  sh.puts 'source script.sh'
  sh.puts 'hello'
  sh.close_write
  puts sh.gets
end

# => Hello, World!
```